# How do I check my Capital One 360 account number?

Tags: capital-one-360

I've forgotten the account number for my Capital One 360 account and cannot find where I had it stored. I'm not able to set up services like Direct Deposit without my account number.

I haven't been locked out of my account, as I can still login with my account's username and password.

**Is there a way to check my Capital One 360 account number online?**

Comment: "Seeding" questions is an okay thing to do, but these two seem like somewhat trivial operations that aren't going to stump a lot of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [Capital One Support - Customer Number](http://helpcenter.capitalone360.com/Topic.aspx?category=C3COMCUSTN)

> Your Account Number identifies each Capital One 360 account you may
>   have and is often used to set up transactions like Direct Deposit,
>   paying bills or making purchases. You can have more than one Account
>   Number.
>
> **You can find your Account Number:**
>
> - **On your Capital One 360 statement under ‘Your Savings Summary’.**
> - **On your account(s) summary after signing into [capitalone360.com](https://www.capitalone360.com).**

[image: Capital One 360 Account Number]